# Blazor Web Assembly (wasm) won't expire client side cookie until page is refreshed

Tags: authentication, jwt, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am using the lastest .NET 5 Blazor Web Assembly Core Hosted template available in Visual Studio 2019. It already has support for authentication out of the box.

The issue is that I can expire the Cookie on the .NET Hosted (server) side like this in Startup.cs in the method  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => 
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;     
        });
```

However, my requirement is that when the session expires after 20 minutes, the user should be asked to login again. My problem with this is that the cookie only expires if the browser is closed or the user hits reload. In the meantime, I can hit all the controllers even if they have the [Authorize] tag in them. The ideal situation is when the user calls a controllers then it redirects to login.

[image]
Cookies are created after login.

[image]
When time has passed cookies are gone, but the user still has all permissions.

Comment: The issue is with the Authentication State that is never updated of the fact that your user is no longer authenticated as the cookie has expired. The solution requires some investment and knowledge on your part. Generally speaking, you should implement the Authentication State provider, in which you should have code ( loop ) that check whether the cookie is going to expire, say, in twenty minute's time, and if it is, you may warn your user of the fact, perhaps ask him to log out and log in, etc. You may also have code here to verify other factors....

Comment: Before you go on with your project using IdentityServer make sure you've read this article ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers/#comments ) by Microsoft , and its accompanied comments. Personally, I'm done with IdentityServer.

Comment: @enet do you have an example where this is done? I can't seem to find anything on the web.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not aware of any code sample on the Internet doing it... However, you should start by inspecting the RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider class and its derived class (Note: It's Blazor Server, not WebAssembly, but it should give you the idea how you should implement the Authentication State Provider). You'll need to override a certain method which has access to your cookie's expiration time, and such like data... and from that method you'll need to trigger an event that may be subscribed by the MainLayout component to notify that the cookie has expired, is going to..etc

Answer (score 1):

Add a Utilities.js javaScript file to wwwroot/js in the Client Project with the following function.

```
function initializeInactivityTimer(dotnetHelper) {
var timer;
document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(logout, 1200000);
}

function logout() {
    dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync("Logout");
}}
```

Make sure you add it to the end of wwwroot/index.html

```
 <script src="js/Utilities.js"></script>
```

In the Server project in MainLayout.razor add the following method

```
[JSInvokable]
public async Task Logout()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationState;
    if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

Make sure you add to the top the MainLayout.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject IJSRuntime js
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager
```

Also add this Cascading Parameter

```
[CascadingParameter]
public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationState { get; set; }
```

Still on MainLayout.razor on Task OnInitializedAsync(), call the javascript function like this:

```
await js.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeInactivityTimer",  DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
```

Keep all modifications on StartUp.cs. They are good for when the user reloads or closes the browser. This js function will log out the user if there is no mouse movement or keys are pressed.

Reference

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOV0uV_E6bU

https://github.com/gavilanch/BlazorMovies/tree/master/ASP.NET%20Core%205/Module%207%20-%20Security